# Restkit: POST array of objects fetched from Core Data to server

Tags: objective-c, json, core-data, restkit

I seem to have some issues with posting an array of Core Data objects to the server.  RestKit makes GET requests very easy, but when it comes to posting not so much.

Here is the they way the server wants the JSON

```
{
   "myThingList":[
      {
       "id":"0",
       "code":"8406014415007DC8",
       "timestamp":"2012-05-11-12.30.15.505000",
       "status":"0",
       "userId":"8000000",

      }
  ]
}
```

I have a THING class in Core Data that holds up to 200 things. I need to send all those at once to the server. Of course, my NSArray after I fetch from CD is just an Array of THINGS.

Below is my code. I am getting [ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key theId.'

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *thingMapping = [ RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[thingMapping class] 
                                                                      inManagedObjectStore:self.objectManager.objectStore ];
[thingMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"theId"];
[thingMapping mapKeyPath:@"code" toAttribute:@"code"];
...... the rest of the fields in Thing

[self.objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:thingMapping forKeyPath:@"myThingList"];

attendReadMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"theId";


[self.objectManager.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[thingMapping inverseMapping] forClass:[Things class]];

//now, we create mapping for the MySyncEntity
RKObjectMapping *syncEntityMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MySyncEntity class]];
[syncEntityMapping mapKeyPath:@"mySyncArray" toRelationship:@"mySyncArray" withMapping:thingMapping];
[[self.objectManager mappingProvider] setSerializationMapping:[syncEntityMapping inverseMapping]
                                          forClass:[MySyncEntity class]];




MySyncEntity *mySyncInstance = [[MySyncEntity alloc] init];
mySyncInstance.mySyncArray = things;


NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"things];

if ( [things count] > 0 ) {
    [self.objectManager sendObject:mySyncInstance toResourcePath:url usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* postLoader) {
        postLoader.delegate = aDelegate;
        postLoader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
        postLoader.userData = @"howdy";
        postLoader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON; 
        [postLoader setUsername:[prefs objectForKey:@"me"]];
        [postLoader setPassword:[prefs objectForKey:@"me"]];


        postLoader.targetObject = nil;  // Map the results back onto a new object instead of self
}]}};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Below needs to be changed

```
** OLD **
 [syncEntityMapping mapKeyPath:@"mySyncArray" toRelationship:@"mySyncArray" withMapping:thingMapping];


** NOW **
[syncEntityMapping mapKeyPath:@"myThingList" toRelationship:@"myThingList" withMapping:thingMapping];
```

MySyncEntity class also needed to have its NSArray Prop changed to the same name "myThingList" instead of "mySyncArray"

Also this

```
mySyncInstance.mySyncArray = things;
```

Needs to be

```
mySyncInstance.myThingList = things;
```